# AjaxFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete & OnUploadComplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on an application and I have a AjaxFileUpload control.  I set OnClientUploadComplete  to a javascript function and OnUploadComplete to a method in my code behind(.cs).

In which order do these run?  Or do they run in parallel?

In my OnUploadComplete i'm moving images from a tmp folder to a CDN.  An in my OnClientUploadComplete i'm retrieving a new list of images, however, it doesn't seem to get the updated list unless i refresh the entire page.  That is why i'm assuming these methods run in parallel.

Is there a way to get the OnClientUploadComplete to run AFTER the OnUploadComplete is done?

Comment: Instead of `OnClientUploadComplete`,  please try using `OnClientUploadCompleteAll` to call it after the `OnUploadComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method in **OnClientUploadComplete**. So the method will be execute after completion of time provided in setTimeout() meanwhile **OnUploadComplete** will execute.